# My submit and clear buttons are not working in my form

Tags: html, css, forms, button

Hello I'm pretty new to coding and while working on a project I tried to make a form with a submit and reset button, but when testing the form it doesn't work on the computer or mobile. Thank you for viewing this.
  enter code here

```
<form id="form" action="contactform.php" method="post">
            <label for="topic">Message Topic: </label>
            <select name="topic">
  <option value="Memberships">Memberships</option>
  <option value="Careers">Careers</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<br><br>
        <label for="Name">Name: </label>
        <br>
    <input name="FName" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First" size="20" required>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input name="LName" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last" size="20" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="email">Email: </label><br>
    <input name="Email" id="email" type="email" size="25" required><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label><br>
    <input name="Phone" id="phone" type="tel" size="12" required>
    <br><br>
    <label for="message">Enter a Message Here:</label>
    <br>
    <br><textarea name="messagebox" id="message"></textarea>
    <br><br>
   <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></button>
    <input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear"></button> 
    <br>      
        </form>
</div>
</body>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $(#submit).on('click touch', function () {
                alert("You are about to SUBMIT this form. Is that ok?");
              });
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is in your syntax. Change it to:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" id="clear">Clear</button>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
<input type="reset" id="clear"  value="clear">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I just checked it. Seems like it works fine
Have a look at it:
  https://codepen.io/kap1l/pen/gOYjjRZ?editors=1000
```

Thanks,

Also in submit and reset type you are using `<input>`
but closing is
     `</button>`
Change both to either 
   `<input></input>`
or  `<button></button>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you didn't assign single quotes or double quotes in the $(#submit).
Change '#submit' to the id of the form and change 'click touch' to 'submit'.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#form').on('submit', function () {
          alert("You are about to SUBMIT this form. Is that ok?");
          return true;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of issues in your code

1. Remove the closing tags `</button>`, firstly because you do not have corresponding opening tags for them, secondly you need not use them as you already achieved the same by using `<input>` elements.
2. JQuery issue, you need to enclose id within double quotes/single quotes

   **$(#submit)** should be **$("#submit")**

***Here is the working code [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajnutf72/)***

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
 <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button> 

 $("#submit").on('click', function () {
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></button>
<input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear"></button>

$(#submit).on('click touch', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html, u did some mistakes like for submit buttons, you started with `<input>` and trying to close it with `<button`>
so replace it with

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
 <input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear"/>
```

In script while using a selector please put the selector inside `""` OR `''` like `$('#submit')` insted of using it `$(#submit)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').on('click', function () {
       alert("You are about to SUBMIT this form. Is that ok?");
    });
 });
```

```css
label{
font-size:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}

textarea
{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" action="contactform.php" method="post">

<table>
<tr>
<td> <label for="topic">Message Topic: </label></td>
<td>
 <select name="topic">
     <option value="Memberships">Memberships</option>
    <option value="Careers">Careers</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
   </select>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  <label for="Name">Name: </label></td>
<td>
  <input name="FName" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First" size="20" required>
    <input name="LName" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last" size="20" required>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>   <label for="email">Email: </label></td>
<td>
  <input name="Email" id="email" type="email" required>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>   <label for="phone">Phone Number: </label></td>
<td>
   <input name="Phone" id="phone" type="number" required>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>  <label for="message">Enter a Message Here:</label></td>
<td>
 <textarea name="messagebox" rows=5 id="message"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"/>
 <input type="reset" id="clear" value="Clear"/>   
 </td>

</tr>

</table>

   
   

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still having the same problem. I made the changes but my buttons still will not work.

Comment: @MarkyMarthaStewartZamiar What is not working you are telling?Run the above snippet and try

Comment: ok so I think figured out the problem. The above code does work but when the form gets to close to the left side of the page it stops working. When I try to do form{ margin-left: 1400px; for the css it does work. But when I try bring the form towards the left it stops working like form{ margin-left: 300px; I'm not sure whats going on?

Comment: @MarkyMarthaStewartZamiar should i make it align?